# Getting Bean Configuration error in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot

***in this controller***

```
package com.example.letsgo.RideDetails.Controller;

import com.example.letsgo.RideDetails.Dto.Request.CancelRideRequestDto;
import com.example.letsgo.RideDetails.Service.CancelRideService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ride")
public class CancelRideController {

    @Autowired
    private CancelRideService cancelRideService;

    @Autowired
    private CancelRideRequestDto cancelRideRequestDto;


    @PutMapping("/{rideNumber}/cancelRide")
    public ResponseEntity<String> cancelRide(@PathVariable("rideNumber") String rideNumber){
        CancelRideRequestDto cancelRideRequestDto1 = new CancelRideRequestDto();
        cancelRideService.cancelRide(cancelRideRequestDto);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Ride Cancelled By Customer");
    }

}
```

***am getting this error***

Description:

Field cancelRideRequestDto in com.example.letsgo.RideDetails.Controller.CancelRideController required a bean of type 'com.example.letsgo.RideDetails.Dto.Request.CancelRideRequestDto' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.letsgo.RideDetails.Dto.Request.CancelRideRequestDto' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 0

when am running the application , am getting this error. i have already implied lombok in my dto.

Comment: Remove the autowired field for you dto, that isn't a spring managed bean nor should be a spring managed bean.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make much sense: why do you need a `cancelRideRequestDto1`? What are you doing with `rideNumber`? I expect something like

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ride")
public class CancelRideController {

    @Autowired
    private CancelRideService cancelRideService;

    @PutMapping("/{rideNumber}/cancelRide")
    public ResponseEntity<String> cancelRide(@PathVariable("rideNumber") String rideNumber){
        CancelRideRequestDto cancelRideRequestDto = new CancelRideRequestDto(rideNumber);
        cancelRideService.cancelRide(cancelRideRequestDto);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Ride Cancelled By Customer");
    }

}
```

Presumably, it is the service which is a Spring bean (and so, a candidate for autowiring); (in this case) the [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) should be a plain object which will carry the required data from the controller to the service.

Even better, consider, if possible, to expone endpoints that use [RESTful conventions](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/#delete):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ride")
public class CancelRideController {

    @Autowired
    private CancelRideService cancelRideService;

    @DeleteMapping("/{rideNumber}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> cancelRide(@PathVariable("rideNumber") String rideNumber){
        CancelRideRequestDto cancelRideRequestDto = new CancelRideRequestDto(rideNumber);
        cancelRideService.cancelRide(cancelRideRequestDto);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Ride Cancelled By Customer");
    }

}
```